# Cutting a string with regular expression

Tags: c#

I have a string containing some tags in it.

Example: **asp.net vb6 crystal-reports**

I use a regular expression to cut this string into several tags like below:

```
string[] technos = Regex.Split(technoString, @"\W+");

foreach (var techno in technos)
{
    ...
 }
```

The problem is that this regular expression is wrong: it produces too much tags. I mean asp.net must be only one tag and crystal-reports must also be only one tag.

At this time, the regular expression gives me the following tags:

- asp
- net
- vb6
- crystal
- reports

and I would like

- asp.net
- vb6
- crystal-reports

Does someone know which regular expression to use?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `string.Split` with a space as the split character?

Comment: Have you tried spliting by space char? You don't have to use regex to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `String.Split`?

```
string str = "asp.net vb6 crystal-reports";
string[] parts = str.Split(); // Uses space as default separator
```

`parts` is an array of strings which contain the desired output.

Comment: You need an argument to `string.Split()`.

Comment: From MSDN : `If the separator parameter is Nothing or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters.`

Comment: +1 but I don't like to use var when the data type text is not too large and using var always make the readability of code lesser

Comment: "using var always make the readability of code lesser" ==> strongly disagree, but in this case putting the explicit type might be better, I'll edit.

Answer (score 3):

If it's just spaces, why not do

```
technoString.Split(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it work to split on whitespace?

```
string[] technos = Regex.Split(technoString, @"\s+");
```

If it's just normal spaces, use the normal split:

```
string[] technos = technoString.Split();
```